# Angular2 Testing Template Driven Forms disabled attribute

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a template driven form with many inputs like the following

```
<input type="text" name="data" [(ngModel)]="data" [disabled]="disabled" />
```

I want to write a test which will ensure that all inputs are disabled when the `disabled` variable is set to true. Below is my test so far. It works, but there are several "disabled" properties on `element` and `element.nativeElement` which remain false. Plus, the rendered view in Chrome when stopped in the debugger doesn't look disabled. Only the "ng-reflect-is-disabled" attribute is actually true.

```
it("should disable all inputs when disabled is true", () => {
    component.disabled = true;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    inputs = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input'));
    inputs.forEach(element => {
        expect(element.attributes["ng-reflect-is-disabled"]).toBe('true');
    });

  });
```

Is there a better way that I can actually check the disabled state of my input?

Comment: have the same issue? did you solve it?

Comment: I have since switched to reactive forms which doesn't use the `[disabled]` directive